# Always check for Shibboleth login without redirecting

Tags: php, environment-variables, symfony, shibboleth

I am writing a Symfony app that has a firewall that uses Shibboleth as its SSO. The way it works is it looks to the environment variable REMOTE_USER and if it exists, it knows its logged in and sets up the user in a custom user provider.

The issue: Environment variables are only valid for the 1 request, so it it constantly looking to Shibboleth to check it's logged in.

So I somehow need to get the environment variables to exist before the start of the page load (if the user is logged in). So is there a way to get Apache (on RedHat) to look to Shibboleth for details, but if not logged in, not redirect to the login?

Comment: Most applications that use SAML authentication (or any sort of external authentication for that matter) set their own cookie once they are satisfied that a user has authenticated. This way, the external authentication is triggered only on the absence or expiration of the application's cookie.

Comment: Yeh, Symfony works a bit differently, it takes parameters from a yaml file that looks to an env variable, not a cookie. I am looking at ways to bypass this and make it look to a session variable rather than an env variable as another option.